# Automated .gitlab-ci.yml lftp configuration

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, lftp

I'm using lftp to automated gitlab ci deployments. I run a script to deploy my code, except 'static' files that I need to upload to other server. Here a sample of my current code.

```
script:
- >
  lftp
  -e "mirror
  --exclude ^\.git.*
  --exclude-glob *.sql
  --exclude-glob *.sqlite3
  --exclude-glob *.txt
  --exclude-glob *.csv
  --exclude-glob *.pyc
  --exclude settings.py
  --exclude migracion/
  --exclude static/
  --exclude ^Resources/Private/
  --exclude \.gitlab-ci.yaml
  -eRv $CI_PROJECT_DIR /pro/ject/dirs; quit;"
  sftp://$ACC
```

This works fine but after this, I have to upload by hand the static files to the static files server. Can you help me with a script that only fetch files in all static folders? Static folders can be in root and inside other folders. Many Thx.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use :

```
lftp -u username,passwd ftp.foobar.cmo \
     -e "mirror -e -R -x .git -x static/ -p ./ dev-site ; quit"
```

Where, in mirror :

- `-e` : remove files that doesn't exist anymore
- `-R` : means you upload from local machine to ftp server
- `-x` : specify a directory to exlude. You can have more than one `-x`
- `-p` : parallelize
- `./` : local dir you want upload
- `dev-site` : remote dir where upload have to go. Take care about the remote dir parameter :

  - if it end with a trail (`dev-site/`), your current dir will be uploaded **INSIDE** this dir on the ftp server
  - if it doesn't end with a trail (`dev-site`), your current dir will be uploaded **AS** this dir on the ftp server

If yout to use this with GitLab CI to upload your static-generated documentation, here is an example `.gitlab-ci.yml` with `mkdocs` + `lftp`:

```
# Build static html site with mkdocs :
build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - mkdocs build
 # first upload, exclude static files:
  - lftp -u ftp_username,$FTP_PASSWORD ftp.foobar.org -e "mirror -x static -R -p site dev ; quit"
 # upload only static to other server:
 - lftp -u ftp_username,$FTP_PASSWORD ftp.otherserv.org -e "mirror -R -p static/ remote/dir ; quit"
```